# Annoying PhpMyAdmin export feature

Tags: mysql, excel, csv

I wonder if any other users of PhpMyAdmin for Mysql have come across this niggle? Normally when exporting the results of  a sql query, you're given options (eg what format to export in , name of filename etc). However above a certain number of rows, these options are not available and you can only see the sql on the normal window. Obviously there are workarounds (I do a copy => Paste Special => Unicode text) but I wonder if anyone's got it working correctly? Changing the Show and Repeat Headers value on the screen doesn't seem to enable the export to csv option for larger (ie > 100) data sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phpmyadmin is always limited by the local PHP Settings. If you have shell access, I would recommend you using the [mysqldump command](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html).

```
shell> mysqldump [options] db_name [tables]
shell> mysqldump [options] --databases db_name1 [db_name2 db_name3...]
shell> mysqldump [options] --all-databases
```

Comment: Thx for that - I'm aware of different ways of doing this, and your suggestion is probably the best option for exporting tables. However i'm looking at various sql queries to export data from. I suppose I could always create temporary tables..

Comment: What about the MySQL Query Browser?

Comment: You're right, there are various workarounds rAyt - thanks for your suggestions. I was just wondering if there was a phpmyadmin setting I could change to enable exporting (in this case to csv files) from phpMyAdmin where a query brings back more than 100 rows. If there isn't I'll continue with a workaround, so no big deal.